# How use Data annotations directly in models

Tags: c#, wpf, mvvm

I'm on a project Csharp MVVM and I would like to know if it was possible to use Data.Annotations directment in models , not ViewModels . If so how ?

I thought like that,
My Model (class Ticket):

```
 [Dapper.Key]
 [Required(ErrorMessage = "This field is requierd")]
 [Range(1, int.MaxValue, ErrorMessage ="Only Int")]
 public int? Tic_Id { get; set; }

 [Required(ErrorMessage = "This field is requierd")]
 public DateTime Tic_Date { get; set; }
```

My ViewModel (use IDataErrorInfo):

```
    [RaisePropertyChanged]
    public virtual Ticket FicheItem {get;set;}
```

And my View

```
 <!-- ID -->
        <TextBlock Grid.Row="1" Text="ID :" Style="{StaticResource FicheLabelStyle}"/>
        <TextBox  Name="ID" Grid.Row="1" Grid.Column="1"
                   IsEnabled="True" 
                   Text="{Binding  FicheItem.Tic_Id, UpdateSourceTrigger=PropertyChanged,ValidatesOnDataErrors=True,NotifyOnValidationError=True,Mode=TwoWay}"  
                   Style="{StaticResource FicheTextboxStyleNumber}"/>
        <TextBlock Grid.Column="1" Grid.Row="2" Name="IDError" Text="{Binding (Validation.Errors)[0].ErrorContent, ElementName=ID}" Foreground="Red" Margin="19,3,0,0"
                   Visibility="{Binding ElementName=IDError, Path=Text,Converter={StaticResource FicheErrorVisibilityConverter},Mode=TwoWay,UpdateSourceTrigger=PropertyChanged}"/>


        <!-- Date -->
        <TextBlock Grid.Row="3"  Text="Date :" Style="{StaticResource FicheLabelStyle}"/>
        <TextBox Grid.Row="3" Grid.Column="1"  Name="Date"
                 Text="{Binding FicheItem.Tic_Date, ValidatesOnDataErrors=True, NotifyOnValidationError=True,UpdateSourceTrigger=PropertyChanged}"  
                 Style="{StaticResource FicheTextboxStyleText}" />
        <TextBlock Grid.Column="1" Grid.Row="4" Name="DateError" Text="{Binding (Validation.Errors)[0].ErrorContent, ElementName=Date}" Foreground="Red" Margin="19,3,0,0"
                   Visibility="{Binding ElementName=DateError, Path=Text,Converter={StaticResource FicheErrorVisibilityConverter},Mode=TwoWay,UpdateSourceTrigger=PropertyChanged}"/>
```

But it doesn't work...

Comment: Don't use models directly in your views, it creates tight coupling from View and Model. The main purpose of MVVM is decouple them.

Comment: Ok so i have to separated properties of my Model in my viewModel and use data annotations it that. But using an orm(dapper) I must , at a given moment it together in an object ? example: cnn.Insert(myObject).
i could do like that each time , new Item{ prop = my separate property....} so if i have so much fields....

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You have to implement the `IDataErrorInfo` interface on the `Ticket` class. Then in the indexed property `this[string propertyName]` you can use [Validator.TryValidateProperty](https://msdn.microsoft.com/it-it/library/system.componentmodel.dataannotations.validator.tryvalidateproperty(v=vs.110).aspx) method and a [ValidationContext](https://msdn.microsoft.com/it-it/library/system.componentmodel.dataannotations.validationcontext(v=vs.110).aspx).

```
public class Ticket : IDataErrorInfo
{
    [Required(ErrorMessage = "This field is required")]
    [Range(1, int.MaxValue, ErrorMessage = "Only Int")]
    public int? Tic_Id { get; set; }

    [Required(ErrorMessage = "This field is required")]
    public DateTime? Tic_Date { get; set; }

    string IDataErrorInfo.Error
    {
        get
        {
            /* It can be improved */        
            return String.Empty;
        }
    }

    string IDataErrorInfo.this[string propertyName]
    {
        get
        {
            Type objectType = GetType();
            PropertyInfo propertyInfo = objectType.GetProperty(propertyName);
            object propertyValue = propertyInfo.GetValue(this, null);
            List<System.ComponentModel.DataAnnotations.ValidationResult> results 
                = new List<System.ComponentModel.DataAnnotations.ValidationResult>();

            ValidationContext validationContext = 
                new System.ComponentModel.DataAnnotations.ValidationContext(this, null, null);
            validationContext.MemberName = propertyName;

            return Validator.TryValidateProperty(propertyValue, validationContext, results) ?
                String.Empty : results[0].ErrorMessage;
        }
    }
}
```

Comment: I thank you I opted for all your solution works very well! but the problem is that with the validation by default, it just make controls in addition to my management Error! example, on a blocking me decimal points or point and shows me an error message saying, the value can not be converted. But I've never create this message! how would you remove?

Comment: Without your code @CamilleColvray it is hard to say something. Maybe this [question](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/6123880/how-to-handle-exception-in-value-converter-so-that-custom-error-message-can-be-d) can help you with your new issue. Otherwise you should post your code (maybe in a new question)